# Ehcache without database table

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I have an `Entity` that right now it's stored on my `database` via `Hibernate`.

I'd like to remove it from database (as i'm not interested to relate it with other data, or to make some query) and i'd like to persist it on `EHCache` and dump all data on file ones a day.

I was wondering if i could do that without having an entity linked to database table.
What is your experience?

Comment: I don't get the question. EHCache has absolutely no relationship to databases at all.

Comment: Now i'm using Ehcache as second-level cache with Hibernate.

Comment: Okay, so Hibernate provides a second-level cache and it just so happens to allow EhCache to be used for that. But that is not the way that EhCache is primarily designed to be used, you can also use it directly. And it has wonderful documentation showing you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it can't work the way you expect it to work.

Hibernate stores a dehydrated entity representation, so using the EHcache data directly will require you to implement a hydration/dehydration processing logic.

If you plan on porting to a non-standard data store, like using a persistent cache as a database, you need more control than Hibernate offers you.

I would try to replace Hibernate 2nd level cache with a service-layer caching implementation (e.g. Spring or even your custom caching abstraction layer). This way you control how the data is going to be serialized/deserialized.

But this is a significant amount of work, so I suggest you take a look on [Redis](http://redis.io/).